# Get Serial Number of Hololens

Tags: uwp, hololens

Can serial number of a hololens be obtained programmatically?

Forums only say how it can be obtained manually:

> Serial number is printed on the device. Flip the device over, the serial number is printed on the frame just behind the right eye glass

Answer (score 1):

This feature seems to be coming in RS5, which is a mandatory update coming fairly soon.

The [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-insider) say that you can:

> Read device hardware info through MDM so devices can be tracked by
>   serial #
>   IT administrators can see and track HoloLens by device serial
>   number in their MDM console.